# Run command line code programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using this code run in windows command prompt..
But I need this done programmatically using C# code

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connection
>   Strings" "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\connection string\DNN"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You may use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start(
    @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe",
    @"-pdf ""connection Strings"" ""C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\connection string\DNN"""
);
```

or if you want more control over the shell and be able to capture for example the standard output and error you could use [`the overload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) taking a `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe")
{
    Arguments = @"-pdf ""connection Strings"" ""C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\connection string\DNN""",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: You could redirect the standard output, wait for the process execution to finish and then read it.

Answer (score 36):

try this

```
ExecuteCommand("Your command here");
```

call it using process

```
 public void ExecuteCommand(string Command)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
        Process Process;

        ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + Command);
        ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

        Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
    }
```

Comment: use /c instead /k if you want to get output :D

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to do that using a process

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe ";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"{0} ""{1}""" ""{2}""","-pdf","connection Strings" ,"C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\connection string\DNN");
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        string outPut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        proc.Close();
```