# Programmatically Start/Stop Recording in Kinect Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am wondering if there is a way to control the start/stop recording feature in Kinect Studio, such that a video is recorded only when a specific event occurs over a long period of time. One idea I had was to find a way to interface to Kinect Studio from Visual Studio, but I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: [RecordAndPlaybackBasics-WPF](https://github.com/angelaHillier/RecordAndPlaybackBasics-WPF) may help you.

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? 1.x or 2.0?

Comment: @Vito Gentile, I am using SDK version 2.0.

Comment: @Rafaf Tahsin That sample code is really helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [KSUtil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785527.aspx), a command line tool that ships with Kinect Studio and by which you can record Kinect data programmatically.

You can you a syntax like this:

```
KSUtil.exe -record <xef_file_path> <duration> –stream depth ir body
```

More info about KSUtil are available on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785527.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to use this tool.

Comment: Done! And, it worked I can record using the command line. However, since I will need to record programmatically, I am wondering if you know how I can access the command line from Visual Studio (if possible) or if you know a resource that could explain how to do this? Thanks again.

Comment: [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738168/run-command-line-code-programatically

Comment: @RafafTahsin Thanks that helps!