# Running a cmd command from within my C# code

Tags: c#, cmd, osrm

I'm currently hosting [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/) locally on my machine to build a routing application. When the application starts, a `bool ServiceAvailable` is checked with a test query to see if the application is available and running locally. I want to be able to start the OSRM application should this `bool` return false. I found a [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738168/run-command-line-code-programatically) with a similar issue and tried to implement it, but the application doesn't load. Here's my current code:

```
    private void StartOSRMService()
    {
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c cd users/james/desktop/osrm/osrm-backend/osrm_release";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c osrm-routed wales-latest.osrm";
    }
```

The method is ran but the service never starts. In other methods, my code breaks due to a `Http.Web` request error, due to the lack of the service.

Comment: The 2nd  `process.StartInfo.Arguments` assignment overwrites the first,  did you mean `+=` (with a space)?

Comment: And you do not call `process.Start()`. You only _configure_ the process, but never run it.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to run 2 commands in one go, why not change the working directory to be "c:\users/james/desktop/osrm/osrm-backend/osrm_release" and then the command would be "osrm-routed wales-latest.osrm" rather than a parameter

Comment: I added `process.Start()` to the end of my method and set the current working directory to the `osrm_release` directory and it's still not running the command. I altered the `osrm-routed...` to `explorer .` so it would open the current directory and nothing has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
    private void StartOSRMService()
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\users\james\desktop\osrm\osrm-backend\osrm_release\osrm-routed.exe");
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\users\james\desktop\osrm\osrm-backend\osrm_release";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.Arguments = "wales-latest.osrm";
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

More info on [Process.Start()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx)

Also, based on your original StartInfo.Arguments, the "`/C`" tells to console to terminate after the command has been executed, thus, if the "`osrm-routed`" is the service that needs to run in the console, and the console is terminated, then the application itself will also terminate when the console terminates.

Comment: I think it was the `/c` that was stopping this from working. Your solution worked perfectly, thanks.