# How to create dotnet core project using c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We can create solutions and project using dotnet core command line. But I want to run this commands in my web application and create a project automatically and download it.

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] string projectName)
{
    // dotnet dotnet new sln --name projectName

   return created solution zip file
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can call dotnet cli for that, if sdk is installed on machine, where your web app is running

Comment: How can I call cli from application?

Comment: in the same way with any command line, there are a lot of questions about it, like this [Run command line code programmatically using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738168/run-command-line-code-programmatically-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Servers' security policies and restrictions won't let you run 'dotnet' process directly. I see only one solution. You can create templates on side, then you could just rename things in your code, package them and send them back to users.

Comment: Create all projects templates and save them as Zip file, then return it as file response. easy solution without a security issue.

Comment: @XAMT this is another way for solution, but how can I set name of peoject solution?

Comment: @barteloma; Save all files in MS SQL file table, Rename the csproj file in runtime and return files as zip file. Or using Install package products (e.g. InstallShield).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this code but it should be something like this

```
[HttpGet("create-proj")]
public ActionResult CreatProject(string name)
{
    var args = "dotnet dotnet new sln --name {name}";

    var p = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = args,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        }
    };

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

   // Zip solution in WorkingDirectory and return that file
}
```

Make sure you installed .NET Core SDK on machine.

Comment: It'll throw 'Access denied'

Comment: You new admin privilege to start external process.

Comment: How do you publish your backend to execute admin tasks? I think it's not in the nature of it all, plus, I assume, it could start a process, but only if it's in the local path and not outside, and doesn't require admin privileges.

Comment: Well there are several ways to handle permission which has nothing to do with your actual question. Of course you should consider of security matter in this case.

Comment: Then, please, handle permissions in your code and post it in its working version.